Why is Burt Munro still the 1000cc record holder, 60+ years later?
In the movie The World's Fastest Indian, New Zealander Burt Munro set a record of 200 mph on his Indian bike. This record has stood for 60 years in the under 1000cc category.
I'm curious about the specific restrictions of this category. Given that there are currently bikes under 1000cc with higher speed capabilities, why hasn't Munro's record been broken?
Is the category still active, or has it been discontinued, which might explain why no one has tried to break the record?

I'm unsure why you've rolled your question back to Edit #2. My edit was to remove some chatter, fix the grammar and remove a sub-question that isn't really on-topic here.

Because the question is about what is the category. Not, why wasn't the record been broke. @Valorum Also was looking for what others have tried to break that record since him.

I felt that "which might explain why no one has tried to break the record?" was actually pretty clear. It's a good question and rolling it back actively harms its readability.

Burt Munro holds the record in a very specific category of motorbike that isn't really operated any more outside of museum pieces and vintage enthusiast collections.

That is to say, that he still holds the Bonneville speed record for a sub-1000cc, streamliner class (frame code S) motorbike, operating a supercharged or turbocharged engine using modified fuel (engine code AF).

The speed record for any 1000cc bike at Bonneville has been repeatedly broken since the 1970s. It's currently held by Al Lamb, who, in 2012, beat the previous record on a Modified Partial Streamlining class (frame code MPS) motorbike operating a Supercharged engine with a Blown Fuel Injection System (BF) using methanol as the fuel source. He drove a top speed of over 260mph!
In 2021 he secured another record, for a Modified Partial Streamline (MPS) motorbike operating a Supercharged or Turbocharged engine with a Blown Fuel Injection System (BF).


But what is that very specific category? I check the record page you link and there are other record with same fame and engine code with faster speed. So what is the difference between those ?

@JuanCarlosOropeza - The category is a combination of those features. There are people who've driven faster 1000cc machines, faster streamliners and faster turbocharged engines, but he holds the record for 1000/S/AF.

For example, Dave Campos holds the streamliner all-time record. His category is 3000/S/AF, but there have been substantially faster drivers driving 3000cc machines using different fuel types and different frames. I've highlighted Mr. Munro's category in the body of the answer in bold.

I see better records with same frame and fuel but smaller engine. That is what doesnt add up. https://i.sstatic.net/fzGTqOj6.png

@JuanCarlosOropeza - Sure, and they hold records in those categories. Think of it like a weight class and sex at the Olympics Judo. There's a champion male in small, medium and large and a champion female in small, medium and large. So there isn't one winner, there are six

Yes, but you don't see the smaller guy beating the big ones. So my guess is there are something else preventing do better 1000/S/AF bikes to break the record on that category.

@JuanCarlosOropeza - You'd see a sprinter beating a sumo wrestler in a running race. Bigger means heavier.
